# Return of PostgreSQL function

Tags: postgresql, types, floating-point

I have a table with a field named `AMOUNT double precision`, and a function that returns another data also `double precision`. What happens is that if I do

```
select (VALUE - function ())
```

where both the `VALUE` as well as the result of the function are equal, the result is still `2.27373675443232e-013`.

I found it very strange and I do not know what to do, since I performed some tests with conversions and rounding and nothing

Anyone have any idea what might be going on?

Answer (score 2):

`double precision` is a lossy data type. The decimal representation you *see* is only an approximation of the internal binary value. The kind of "unexpected" mismatch you see is to be expected when calculating with floating-point numbers.

You could work with a loss-less type like `numeric` to avoid this. (And possibly round to a reasonable number of fractional digits.)

Start by reading the [Postgres manual on numeric data types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html) and at least [one of the many articles out there about floating-point arithmetic](http://blog.reverberate.org/2014/09/what-every-computer-programmer-should.html).

Comment: thank you for the help Ervin. i will try change the type for double to numeric and test.